# Change main view index.vue in nuxt3

Tags: routes, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have a project in nuxt3 with vue3..where I have a file index.vue in the pages folder, which works as the main view http://localhost:3000/...but if I want another view to be the main view for example test.vue and not index.vue could it be?

In my nuxt.config.ts file I had added the following, but it didn't work for me:

```
   import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt/config"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  
  
  
  router: {
    base: '/',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: 'pages/test.vue', 
      },
    ],
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Nuxt expert but from reviewing the documentation, the `router` property of `defineNuxtConfig` is for [configuring vue-router options](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#router), not for configuring **routes**

Following the [documentation for custom routes](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing#adding-custom-routes):

Create an `app/router.options.ts` file

The file should have code that resembles the following

```js
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

// https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routeroptions.html
export default <RouterConfig> {
  routes: (_routes) => [
    {
      name: 'home',
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('~/pages/test.vue').then(r => r.default || r)
    }
  ],
}
```

`test.vue` will now load when visiting the `/` route.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tygpo8?file=pages%2Findex.vue,pages%2Ftest.vue,app%2Frouter.options.ts)